# Neural network grid search value error

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network, grid-search

I am trying to run a grid search for a neural network but I keep getting some weird errors. my algorithm looks like:

```
parameters={'learning_rate':["constant", "invscaling", "adaptive"], 
                 'hidden_layer_sizes': (156,), 'alpha': [10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 7)], 
                 'activation': ["logistic", "relu", "Tanh"]}
grid= GridSearchCV(MLPClassifier(),parameters, n_jobs=-1, cv=10)
grid.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

The error message I get is:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I have tried to also use just 1 value wit regards to the `activation` and `learning_rate` but the problem seem to persist. Is there anything I am not doing well, please?

Comment: The problem still persists even after I tried updating all the involved packages. Meaning the package is not the issue, I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I spotted 2 mistakes in your code.*

---

**First:** The `alpha` parameters should be contained in a pure list. Using List Comprehension, the answer is as follows.

**Second:** In the `'activation': ["logistic", "relu", "Tanh"]}` the `Tanh` should be replaced with `tanh`.

---

### The following code should work fine:

**Replace:**

```
'alpha': [10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 7)]
'activation': ["logistic", "relu", "Tanh"]
```

---

**With:**

```
'alpha': [10.0 ** -i for i in range(1,7)]
'activation': ["logistic", "relu", "tanh"]
```

---

**Putting everything together:**

```
parameters={'learning_rate':["constant", "invscaling", "adaptive"], 
             'hidden_layer_sizes': (156,), 'alpha': [10.0 ** -i for i in range(1,7)], 
             'activation': ["logistic", "relu", "tanh"]}

grid= GridSearchCV(MLPClassifier(), parameters, n_jobs=-1, cv=10)

grid.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

Comment: rectifying what you pointed out made it work. Thanks for your help.